# How to translate a WMP playlist back to English?

Tags: language, mp3, windows-media-player, playlists, translation

I'm using WMP on Windows 10 to manage my .MP3 playlists, and a certain album has gotten itself 'stuck' in a Japanese translation. Presumably it did this after I clicked to update the album info.

[image]

I can get it back to English temporarily by moving the .MP3s to a different folder and editing the playlist accordingly, but I prefer to keep my music files together in an organized central repository. When I point the entries back to the original files, I get the Japanese again (nothing against Japan, I just can't read it). WMP must be storing this somewhere else.

There doesn't seem to be a way to edit this information in the GUI, but I may be overlooking it if it's there. I opened the file in TextPad, but everything's English:

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
        <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Windows Media Player -- 12.0.18362.719"/>
        <meta name="ItemCount" content="0"/>
        <meta name="IsFavorite"/>
        <meta name="ContentPartnerListID"/>
        <meta name="ContentPartnerNameType"/>
        <meta name="ContentPartnerName"/>
        <meta name="Subtitle"/>
        <author/>
        <title>Listen to the Dawn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <seq>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\01 - Yours is My Heart Alone.mp3" cid="{1B33AADC-5BC0-4FA6-A33F-405266FBCEE9}" tid="{D6732473-CF97-48BE-B081-670C2B6728EA}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\02 - My One and Only Love.mp3" cid="{63AB4A2E-CF0E-4C91-9B39-91ED5CEA8B7A}" tid="{6E5CC741-27A6-41CD-B52B-A5253F3D7F91}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\03 - You&apos;re My Everything.mp3" cid="{1B424114-8371-4D32-8EA5-906568EF96B4}" tid="{0E979E8E-85FA-4A4D-8ADA-87EAEAE4C8EF}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\04 - Listen to the Dawn.mp3" cid="{D2FDD1D9-0E5E-4F8C-B34F-AAA3AC5FE7CF}" tid="{53B2894A-9FEF-4162-B6B8-45B06E9070C5}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\05 - Isabella.mp3" cid="{072B1014-1B40-47D6-B8D5-92C6B2A44F00}" tid="{AD30CF1E-FF16-4594-BAB7-742B82CCA9DD}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\06 - It Amazes Me.mp3" cid="{BCDD6C88-2302-444D-9240-12C7623BE9AC}" tid="{FC8104DD-B827-490D-8814-CA8C5E67CFCA}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\07 - Never Let Me Go.mp3" cid="{39029627-F34F-4B0F-918F-12125F5C4765}" tid="{156C56EE-4B97-4AFB-B0CF-A46732E75387}"/>
            <media src="..\..\..\..\Music\Collection\Kenny Burrell\Listen to the Dawn\08 - Papa Joe.mp3" cid="{67D69419-0CE8-4B31-B30D-315250E13123}" tid="{7C4975B4-9936-40EA-8BB2-918B3F18B00E}"/>
        </seq>
    </body>
</smil>
```

How can I get this list back to the English translation while keeping my MP3s in their original folder?

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't stored in the playlist, but rather in the MP3 files themselves as metadata (also called tags). So instead of modifying the playlist, you need to correct the MP3 tags. After having done that, WMP will automatically show the correct information (taken from each file's tags) in the playlist as well.

The simplest way to correct the tags is by doing so in WMP's library itself. Find the song in the library, right-click the piece of information that you want to correct (e.g. artist, title...), select `Edit`, and enter the new info.